# How to find type of AWS CloudWatch Metric's type (Period or Event Driven)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

### What I need

FWIU there are two types of metrics, period-driven (like `CPUUtilization`) and event-driven (`HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count`) I want to find how to find the type of the metric because some of the metric types' type is not unpredictable. For example, AWS ES's `5xx` is period-driven.

I may be wrong in finding the type of metric, I assumed that they're fixed value. But the type of metric could be determined from its usage.

### Why I need

I will give different [Missing Treating Type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarms-and-missing-data) for different metric types, but I can't how to find it via SDK, CDK, or their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CLI, you can use –

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace "<namespace>" --metric-name "<your-metric>"
```

and that should give you everything you need to know about that metric.

Ref – https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/list-metrics.html